# multiple join query select only one of each type

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie on SQL so please don't hesitate to add other comments about the query.

The database i'm working towards is old and is done almost completely without constraints.

this is the query i'm working on:

```
  select cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.Name, prt.Data, pd.language, prt.FileName, pr.resourceType
from 
[AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ConnectedProduct] cp
left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[Product] p
on cp.connectedId = p.id
left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductResource] pr
on cp.connectedId = pr.id and cp.Company = pr.Company
inner join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductDescription] pd
on cp.connectedId = pd.id and cp.Company = pd.Company
left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductResourceThumbnail] prt
on cp.connectedId = prt.ProductId and cp.Company = prt.CompanyName and pr.fileName = prt.FileName
where pd.language = 'en' order by cp.id
```

this is result:
[image]

what i want to do now is pick rows depending on resourceType (the column to the right)

i only want to pick a unique row depending on id, connectedId and language.
I also want it to pick this row by looking if there is a resourcetype with the type "I" first and if there is none of that then pick where resourcetype is "S" and if none of those exist then just take the first row it finds.

here is an example of what i want it too look:

[image]

As you can see it is a unique row on the combined key (id, connectedId and language) and also it selects only one row where the resourcetypeid = "I".
So even if there is a lot of other rows with the same combined key i want it to select one row where first the resourcetypeid = "I" and if that not exists then i want it to take the row where resourcetypeid = "S" and if that not exists it can take the first row it finds with the combined key(id, connectedId and language)

My try:

```
SELECT cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.language, pr.resourceType
FROM (
  SELECT cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.language, pr.resourceType
   , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Priority]) AS [RANK]
  FROM (
    SELECT cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.language, pr.resourceType
    , CASE pr.resourceType
       WHEN 'I' THEN 1
      WHEN 'S' THEN 2
      ELSE 3
     END AS [Priority]
   FROM [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ConnectedProduct] cp
        left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[Product] p
          on cp.connectedId = p.id
        left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductResource] pr
        on cp.connectedId = pr.id and cp.Company = pr.Company
        inner join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductDescription] pd
        on cp.connectedId = pd.id and cp.Company = pd.Company
        left join [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductResourceThumbnail] prt
        on cp.connectedId = prt.ProductId and cp.Company = prt.CompanyName and pr.fileName = prt.FileName
WHERE pd.language = 'en'
GROUP BY cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.language, pr.resourceType
  ) AS PrioritizedSelect
 ) AS RankedSelect
WHERE [RANK] = 1
```

this is the errors i get:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
The multi-part identifier "cp.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
The multi-part identifier "cp.connectedId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
The multi-part identifier "pd.language" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
The multi-part identifier "pr.resourceType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
The multi-part identifier "cp.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
The multi-part identifier "cp.connectedId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
The multi-part identifier "pd.language" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
The multi-part identifier "pr.resourceType" could not be bound.

Comment: your describe is not clear, can you give a sample your expect result?

Comment: You are getting the errors because the table aliases are only known in the innermost query. Outside there is no `cp`. So either use `id` instead of `cp.id` or use `PrioritizedSelect.id` and `RankedSelect.id` if you want so. Be aware that `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK` are not what you want here. You want `ROW_NUMBER` instead which gives you exactly one record per group,whereas the other functions could give you several records in case of ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the tables and joins.

1. You outer-join `product` to `connectedproduct`. How can a record in `connectedproduct` even exist when there is no matching record in `product`? Either this should be an inner join or the table names are misleading.
2. Then you outer-join table `productresource` and inner-join table `productdescription` on their `id` and `company`. So when their `id` is linked properly, how could there be a company mismatch? The `id` *is* the tables' primary key, right? So why would a uniquely identified record be linked to `connectedproduct` but have another `company`? This looks dubious. Are you trying to defend against data inconsistencies here?
3. In your results I see many `cp.id` being null. How can a record in a table not have an ID? Either the table *has* an ID, then every record has such an ID for identification *or* it hasn't an ID column at all. A nullable ID makes no sense in a database.

Then you want only the "best" record per `cp.id`, `cp.connectedId`, and `pd.language`. So you want to rank your records. You'd do this by using the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` where you order the records by quality and give the best record per group value #1. Later you'd filter these results to only stay with #1 records.

```
select id, connectedid, name, data, language, filename, resourcetype
from
(
  select 
    cp.id,
    cp.connectedid, 
    pd.name, 
    prt.data, 
    pd.language, 
    prt.filename, 
    pr.resourcetype,
    row_number()
      over(partition by cp.id, cp.connectedId, pd.language
           order by case pr.resourcetype when 'I' then 1 when 'S' then 2 else 3 end) as rn
  from aaes_pam_dev.dbo.connectedproduct cp
  left join aaes_pam_dev.dbo.product p 
    on cp.connectedid = p.id
  left join aaes_pam_dev.dbo.productresource pr
    on cp.connectedid = pr.id 
    and cp.company = pr.company
  inner join aaes_pam_dev.dbo.productdescription pd 
    on cp.connectedid = pd.id 
    and cp.company = pd.company
  left join aaes_pam_dev.dbo.productresourcethumbnail prt 
    on cp.connectedid = prt.productid
    and cp.company = prt.companyname 
    and pr.filename = prt.filename
  where pd.language = 'en' 
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Comment: Hi! For the first question you are right! There shouldn't be a record in connectedProduct if there is not a matching id in the Product table.
For question 2:
All the tables have combines keys. 
ConnectedProduct(id, connectedId, Company)
Product(id, Company)
ProductDescription(id, language, Company)
ProductResource(id, fileName, resourceType, language, Company)
For question 3: The datebase is created in a very poor way. Therefor the data that is created by the old application can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use that structure to construct your request:

```
SELECT Id, ConnectedId, Language, RessourceType
FROM (
  SELECT Id, ConnectedId, Language, RessourceType
   , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Priority]) AS [RANK]
  FROM (
    SELECT Id, ConnectedId, Language, RessourceType
     , CASE RessourceType
       WHEN 'I' THEN 1
       WHEN 'S' THEN 2
       ELSE 3
     END AS [Priority]
    FROM [ ... ]
    WHERE [ ... ]
    GROUP BY Id, ConnectedId, Language, RessourceType
  ) AS PrioritizedSelect
) AS RankedSelect
WHERE [RANK] = 1
```

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure how to use this one tough. I added my try to my last edit.

Comment: Well? Does the results fit your needs or is there a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: I get some errors so i don't really know. I added it as an edit

Comment: Is seems like the two outer selects has no from and can't find their variables?

Comment: You need to use only the names of the fields on the outer SELECT as the aliases only make sense in the first inner SELECT.